# "Line Dripping" effect with css

Tags: html, css

[Very Cool Line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YPCWp.png)

I'm trying to create this line. And actually I did. I'm just wondering is there a better way to achieve this effect? Thank you in advance.

Here is my current code.

```css
.blue-line-1 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 250px auto 0;
  width: 222px;
  height: 24px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 2.375rem;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #61AAFF 0%, #32EBCA 100%);
}

.blue-line-2 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 150px auto 0;
  width: 80px;
  height: 24px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 2.375rem;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #61AAFF 0%, #32EBCA 100%);
}

.blue-line-3 {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px auto 50px;
  width: 30px;
  height: 24px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 2.375rem;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #61AAFF 0%, #32EBCA 100%);
}
```

```html
<div>
  <div class="blue-line-1">
  </div>
  <div class="blue-line-2">
  </div>
  <div class="blue-line-3">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

One element can do it:

```css
.line {
  width: 40px; /* width of all lines*/
  padding-top: 150px; /* height of first line */
  height: 0; /* don't touch this, it will push the lines outside */
  border-radius: 999px; /* a big pixel value */
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, #61AAFF, #32EBCA); /* your gradient */
}
.line:before,
.line:after {
  content: "";
  display: block;
  background: inherit;
  border-radius: inherit;
  margin-top: 10px; /* the gap between lines*/
}
.line:before {
  height: 80px; /* height of second line */
}
.line:after {
  height: 50px; /* height of third line */
}
```

```html
<div class="line"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you this way look a lot better. Although I don't really get how "display: grid;" or "display: block;" affects it and why I can't get the same effect with "display: flex;".

Comment: @YasinDamga on the pseudo element any display different from inline will do the job because you cannot set size to inline element. On the parent element, display: grid will work because it put elements above each other by default which what you want. Using flexbox you will need more properties to achieve the same (column direction, flex-shrink, etc)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a better and easier way!

```
.line {
  position: relative;
  margin: auto;
  width: 30px;
  height: 24px;
  transform: rotate(90deg);
  flex-shrink: 0;
  border-radius: 2.375rem;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #61AAFF 0%, #32EBCA 100%);
}

.line-1 {
  margin-top: 250px;
  width: 100px;
}

.line-2 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 200px;
}

.line-3 {
  margin-top: 200px;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```
<div>
  <div class="line line-1"></div>
  <div class="line line-2"></div>
  <div class="line line-3"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Also thank you. Actually this was what I wanted. I just over-thought about it complicated it for me.